# Ubuntu 16 for 32 bit platform

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, 32-bit

Trying to find Ubuntu for 32bit platform. I was looking ISO full image, but found only mini network installation. Why they don't provide 32bit full iso or I do something wrong while searching?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

32 bits iso image for Ubuntu 16.04 can be found on this page (I searched "ubuntu 16.04 32 bit download" in google) http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ somewhere near the middle of the page.

Direct link here: http://releases.ubuntu.com/16.04/ubuntu-16.04.4-desktop-i386.iso